# problem with JFilechooser in netbeans

Tags: java, swing

I am using netbeans for developing java dextop application,I have created a `JFilechooser` which will let user to save a new file created.

But the this `int returnVal = newFileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);` line of the following code gives this error:

```
method showSaveDialog in javax.swing.JFileChooser cannot be applied to given types
 required: java.awt.Component
 found: netsim.NetSimView
```

here class name is `NetSimView` and source package is `netsim`

```
private void newMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    newFileChooser=new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = newFileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = newFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's expecting an instance of [`java.awt.Component`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) as argument in [`showSaveDialog()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog%28java.awt.Component%29) method, but you aren't passing a valid argument.

You have 2 options:

1. Just pass `null` instead of `this`.
2. Let the class `netsim.NetSimView` extend a `java.awt.Component`.

*Hint: those blueish code things in the 1st sentence are actually links. Click and learn.*

Answer (score 3):

This is where you need to leave the magic of NetBeans aside and RTM.

The JavaDocs for [JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(Component)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog%28java.awt.Component%29) explicitly state that the argument has to be a Component (or by implication, something that extends component).

The Component is used to provide a position for the chooser.

Further down the docs. add.

> Parameters:
>       parent - the parent component of the dialog, can be null; see
>   showDialog for details